# What materials are UV blocking and transparent?

Tags: visible-light, material-science

I am searching for a transparent and UV-A blocking material, which can be bought of the shelf. It should be blocking UV light in the range of 385nm to 405nm.

The data sheets of materials like Polycarbonat are often misleading and stating things like *UV-resistant* which is clearly not what I am looking for.

Is the color of the material important as well?
What do I need to look out for in the data sheets?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You may want to ask an eye doctor.  There must be eyeglass lenses that block UV-A, and an eye doctor would know what material does that.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. If I am not able to find a suitable answer here, this may be an option